# Execution of DalekJS with PHP does not work

Tags: php, exec, dalekjs

I use the testing framework DalekJS to test the user interface. To execute my testing script mytest.js I type into the shell:

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tests
dalek mytest.js
```

and it works fine. Now I would like to execute the same script with PHP. My code:

```
<?php
chdir('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tests');
$command = 'dalek mytest.js';
exec($command, $return, $return_var);
var_dump($return);
var_dump($return_var);
```

Running my PHP-script in browser, it prints:

```
array(0) { } int(127)
```

The DalekJS script generates a screenshot when executing in shell but running with PHP it does not happen anything. I have also tried shell_exec(), system() and passthru() without success.
Do you have any idea why the PHP script does not work?

Comment: what are the chmods of dalek, mytest.js and cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tests? under which user/group run php/webserver?

Comment: I set 'chmod -R 777' (because it is only a test server) and the command 'ls -l' shows -rwxrwxrwx@. I have admin rights for the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Calling dalek from PHP works fine for me. Is it possible your PHP process is running with a different environment (containing `PATH`, amongst other things) that your user? Maybe the apache user or some such?

```
<?php

// change current working directory of the current PHP process,
// this will subsequently change the initial CWD of exec()
$whereMyTestsAre = __DIR__;
chdir($whereMyTestsAre); 

// locate dalek
$dalek = exec('which dalek');

// abort if there is no dalek,
// you may want to check PATH or supply the full path yourself
if (!$dalek) {
  echo "could not find dalek executable, please check your path";
  $PATH = exec('echo $PATH');
  echo '$PATH is ', $PATH, "\n";
  exit(1);
}

// relative to $whereMyTestsAre
// exec() blocks until the child process (dalek) exits
exec('dalek mytest.js');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You were right, there is a problem with the PATH. I couldn't solve that on my Mac yet and your code doesn't work either. But on my Ubuntu it works fine and returns the same like the shell - except for the screenshot function: if the test contrains .screenshot('name.png'), the PHP script takes a long time without finishing (in shell it is trouble-free). Do you have any problems with screenshot() running the test with PHP?

Comment: We don't have any problems with PHP because we are not using PHP. I only pointed out why your original code was flawed - beyond that, I dunno…